# MySQL on Mac OS X Lion - can't connect over internet

Tags: mysql, mac-osx, osx-lion

I've installed MySQL on OSX Lion, however I can't connect to the MySQL server via phpMyAdmin (or Sequel Pro).
I have a domain with 1and1, and created a sub domain (server.domain.com) and created an A record to point to my internet IP (where the server is) and that all works fine.
However when trying to use Sequel Pro to connect to server.domain.com it gives me this error:

```
MySQL said: Access denied for user 'root'@'server.echobarrier.com' (using password: YES).
```

Then when I try connecting to via the Internet IP I get this error:

```
MySQL said: Host '192.168.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

After 'Googling'  I thought it'd be a `GRANT ALL` command to resolve the issue, but I ran the following command and still have the problem:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
```

I've port forwarded 3306 (which I've double checked the MySQL server is running on that port) through my router (and the firewall settings in the router) to the server's LAN IP.

I can't think of anything else. Can anyone else help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grant statement is wrong. It should be:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Did you issue a "flush privileges;" after the grant statement?

Comment: Thank you! I saw that flush privileges earlier, and ran it once. But nothing happened. I assume I had an error as you said and display errors was switched off. I switched it on, realised, and changed it. Thank you so much!